# Symfony4 and RabbitMQ in docker container

Tags: symfony, docker, rabbitmq, docker-compose

I have multiple docker container which provide different things in my working setup. One for web, where my symfony project is mounted as volume. And one for RabbitMQ which should be provided by messages from the symfony project. I build my container with docker-compose and ansible.

This is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    depends_on:
      - db
      - rabbit_mq
    build: ./container/web
    container_name: web
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - [PATH]:/var/www/html/project
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "USER"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "PASS"
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
  rabbit_mq:
    image: "rabbitmq:3-management"
    hostname: "rabbitmq-localhost"
    container_name: rabbitmq
    ports:
      - "15672:15672"
      - "5672:5672"
    volumes:
      - rabbit:/var/lib/rabbitmq
      - "./container/rabbitmq/config/enabled_plugins:/etc/rabbitmq/enabled_plugins"
      - "./container/rabbitmq/config/rabbitmq.config:/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config"
      - "./container/rabbitmq/config/definitions.json:/etc/rabbitmq/definitions.json"
    command:  bash -c "sleep 10; rabbitmq-server;"
volumes:
  mysql_data:
  rabbit:
    driver: local
```

It works everything well, Symfony and RabbitMQ are up and running and I can access the rabbitmq management via http://localhost:15672

Now I try to push a message to my RabbitMQ Queue and I get the error:

```
stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to tcp://127.0.0.1:5672 (Connection refused)
```

Here is my symfony .env configraution

```
RABBITMQ_URL=amqp://user:pass@127.0.0.1:5672/vhost
```

When I inspect the rabbitmq container I can see that its IPAdress is

```
"IPAddress": "172.18.0.3"
```

So when I put this IP to the symfony .env file, I am able to push messages to the queue. But this ip changes every time I rerun the docker container and I don't want to change all the time the symfony configuration. So what is the best practice to manage scenarios like that.

By the way: the database container is accessible via 127.0.0.1:3306 (don't get that at all)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try setting `RABBITMQ_URL=amqp://user:pass@rabbit_mq:5672/vhost`. rabbit_mq is the name of RabbitMQ service and the one you used in depends_on, for MySql you should use `db` as host

[An example](https://github.com/php-enqueue/enqueue-dev/blob/master/docker-compose.yml#L20) for [Enqueue](https://github.com/php-enqueue/enqueue-dev) repository